# Python CGI script permission denied when writing file

Tags: python, io, permissions, cgi

I've got a python script named test.cgi in /Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables. I have an index.html file in /Library/WebServer/Documents. My html file contains a form that posts to the CGI script and that works fine. When my script attempts to write a file I get the following error:

[image]

It doesn't matter what I specify as the output dir, I get the same error message. I've tried changing the permissions on the cgi-bin folder and the script but that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Linux, a web server normally runs as an unprivileged user and group. Often user=www-data and group=www-data, but it depends on your setup. The CGI inherits this user and group.

To create a file as www-data you need to ensure the directory is writable to that user.

One common way is to make sure that the directory is in group www-data and writable. The following commands are an example:

```
$ chgrp www-data /Users/user/Documents/pictures
$ chmod g+rwx /Users/user/Documents/pictures
```

This will only work if you are yourself in group www-data (or root).

You might want to make existing files in that directory writable:

```
$ chgrp www-data /Users/user/Documents/pictures/*
$ chmod g+rw /Users/user/Documents/pictures/*
```

You also need to check that all the directories above /Users/user/Documents/pictures are accessible to www-data. So chgrp/chmod them as well if they are not open to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have the write permissions at some point along the way to /Users/user/Documents/pictures/lol.jpg - you should modify permissions in there accordingly (whilst bearing in mind security implications)

Comment: I went down the line and gave everything 0777 and it works now, but I feel like that's not a very good solution.

Comment: Agreed, you should have checked which layer the issue was at. If this is a public-facing webserver, this might well bite you hard someday (in the meantime though, if you feel this answered your question, you know the deal ;) )